# Angularjs ui grid issue with small set of data (very few rows) but containing huge text for some columns

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui, angular-ui-grid

I am using ui grid in Modal but I am facing problem in representing data with large text. I have only maximum up to 5 rows in my data set. But some of the columns in the rows have huge text. So I would like to have to fixed width for each column and I should  be able to provide horizontal and vertical scroll bars at individual cell level if that particular cell exceeds certain text length ( > 1000). Is it possible to provide horizontal and vertical scroll bars at cell level? Is there any reference code for that?

In the attached image,  under Log Field I have nearly ten thousand words like that I will get up to maximum 5 rows. In each row I will have log field containing nearly 10 to 20 thousand words.

[image: ui-grid]

Comment: can you provide a screenshot ?

Comment: Ramanaa, I have attached image and edited the question.

Comment: Have you tried assigning a cellTemplate to the Log Field column?  Perhaps making it a textarea would give you the behavior you're looking for,